# How to get a for loop to work with tkinter in python 2.7?

Tags: python, user-interface, loops, for-loop, tkinter

I am trying to create a gui widget that will search through a .sql file. II am using tkinter and I have a for loop which is not working. It will only display one result when there many 5.

```
def OnPressEnter(self,event):
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        t = self.entryVariable.get()

        cur.execute("select * from Dict where Def LIKE ? OR word LIKE ? LIMIT 12", ('%'+t+'%', '%'+t+'%'))
        rows = cur.fetchall()

        for row in rows:
            #printing second & third column(See tuples)

            self.labelVariable.set(row[1])

            self.labelVariable.set(row[2])
```

If I type "Apple" I will only get one of my results which is "$499". So how do I get the loop to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the for loop, It's that you are setting the same variable twice. here:

```
for row in rows:
        #printing second & third column(See tuples)
        #sets the variable
        self.labelVariable.set(row[1])
        #sets the variable again to a different value
        self.labelVariable.set(row[2])
```

you could do something like:

```
 label = ""
 for row in rows:
    label += row[1] + ":" + row[2] + "\n"
 self.labelVariable.set(label)
 #print to check the label string
 print label
```

Which generates the string first and then sets the value. The label value should contain the two values with a colon between them with newlines separating the rows.

Comment: I am still only getting one result when there are 5. It seems as if there is something with the loop. [Here is my gui](http://imgur.com/AALHCzk) & my [console is outputting this](http://imgur.com/gaWtQPw).

Comment: You can check out the full code [here](https://github.com/bossman759/wiki-serach/blob/master/gui.py) if that would help.

Comment: move the `label = ""` out of the for loop [here](https://github.com/bossman759/wiki-serach/blob/master/gui.py#L78) and  anywhere else. each iteration you are resetting the value of `label`, throwing away the last row values.

Comment: Let me know if this is the fix, don't forget to upvote/accept if it does. Welcome to StackOverflow!